# v-model two way data binding not working in Nuxt 3 web app

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3, v-model

I was using Nuxt 3 to create a login and signup page for a web app.
This is the code for the login page:

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <label for="email"> Email Address</label>
    <input
      type="email"
      placeholder="The good-old email field"
      name="email"
      id="email"
      v-model="email"
    />
    <label for="password"> Password</label>
    <input
      type="password"
      placeholder="Top secret...."
      name="password"
      id="password"
      v-model="password"
    />
    <div v-if="error.show" class="error">{{ error.message }}</div>
    <button v-if="!isPending" :disabled="!email || !password">Log In</button>
    <button v-if="isPending" disabled>Loading</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useGlobalStore } from "@/stores/global";
import { useAccountStore } from "@/stores/account";

const globalStore = useGlobalStore();
const accountStore = useAccountStore();

const error = computed(() => globalStore.error);
const isPending = ref(false);

const email = ref("");
const password = ref("");

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  isPending.value = true;
  console.log("The user is trying to log in");
  await accountStore.login({
    email: email.value,
    password: password.value,
  });
  isPending.value = false;
};
</script>
```

The problem with this is even when `email` and `password` have been entered, the `submit` button still remains disabled. I have been able to figure out the reason as even when user enters the values for both of them, the values of the refs is not updating.
Can anyone help me figure out why?

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: maybe it's omitted from your snippet but don't you need to `import { ref, computed } from 'vue'` for it to run?  otherwise, do you have any errors in your dev console?  after adding the import statement the rest of your code (minus the store related code) works for me when testing in a codesandbox

Comment: You don't need to import those in Nuxt3, all good there. Meanwhile, please indeed double check your console + Vue devtools to spot any errors.

Comment: There are no errors in the dev console when I run it on the development server. Even I tried running it on codesandbox, but couldn't replicate the error. Any other suggestions as to why it might be happening?

Comment: Hard to help you further if your issue is not reproducable.

Comment: https://github.com/EshaanAgg/assignment-hero/
This is the github link for my repository. The error should be reproducable from here. Maybe it's due to some configuration of Nuxt?

Comment: PS. Pls ignore the README.md which deals with setting up of Appwrite to enable the backend server. It needs to be updated.

Comment: Your repo requires an appwrite backend hooked up in order to run (it's heavily tied into your store configuration).  However, after removing all that code... I get an error in dev console, `TypeError: process.cwd is not a function`.  which is linked to the use of dotenv in `config.js`.  From what I can tell reading the Nuxt3 documentation, dotenv is already built into Nuxt meaning your manual install/use of it is not required, and is seemingly breaking your app. Removing the offending dotenv usage fixes your app.

Comment: I suggest this [tutorial](https://serversideup.net/using-environment-variables-in-nuxt-3/) on how to use env variables in Nuxt 3

Comment: Thanks so much for spotting this error!